# Search through Django objects with json.dumps, serializers and fuse.js

Tags: json, django, fuse.js

I have a list of Django objects (messages) that I am trying to search through using Fuse.js (http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html). From what I understand, Fuse only accepts JSON arrays. I used Django's serializers to serialize my list and then JSON dumps to pass the newly formatted data to my Django template. The search seems to be working (sort of) but it's only returning indices rather than objects and I can't figure out why. Also, it only works if you search for one character at a time. Pardon me for being so new to all of this . . . let me know if my question doesn't even make sense. Here's an example of the console output when I search for the letter 'T'. The full array is at the top and the search results are in blue:

[image]

Here's my view:

```
@login_required
def inbox(request, template_name='django_messages/inbox.html'):

    message_list = Message.objects.inbox_for(request.user)
    json_serialized_list = serializers.serialize("json", message_list)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'message_list': message_list,
        'json_list': json.dumps(json_serialized_list),
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And my template:

```
$(function(){    
// testing a search with fuse.js
              var json_list = {{ json_list|safe }}
              console.log(json_list) 

              var options = {
                  keys: ['fields.subject'],

              } 

              var f = new Fuse(json_list, options);
              var result = f.search('t');
              console.log(result)
});
```

Any ideas?? :)

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code with a similar JSON array, and it works. Be sure to have the right `Fuse.js` library, or use one from a cdn

```js
data = [{"pk": 1, "fields":{"subject": "Welcome"}, "models": "django_messages.message"},
       {"pk": 2, "fields":{"subject": "Test"}, "models": "django_messages.message"}];
var options = {
                  keys: ['fields.subject'],  
              } 

var f = new Fuse(data, options);
var result = f.search('t');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fuse/2.2.0/fuse.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @moses ! It's so strange . . . The json array in the screenshot above is the result of printing {{ json_list|safe }} to the console. When I copy that array and put it directly in the Javascript (like you've done above), the search works perfectly! But if I just run the search on the variable, it returns an empty list of search results. So weird.

Comment: Did you check your `fuse.js`, to be sure its not broken? You can try to replace the `src` with the one I have used

Comment: Yes I tried the cdn you used as well. I must be messing up the array when I pass it from the view or something. :( @moses

Comment: If you think the problem is from the view, you can use `from django.http import  JsonResponse` and do `'json_list': JsonResponse(json_serialized_list)` instead of `json.dumps()` but I'm not certain it will change anything as both are almost the same.

Comment: It didn't change anything. But thanks anyway - thanks for trying to help me!! I appreciate it. @moses